# Update Modal Pop With Ajax Response And Display in Yii

Tags: jquery, yii

I have been trying to render a modal pop up with html data and display the pop up. I have used ajax to get data from the controller and now want to update the modal and show it. The data is displayed correctly the first time and the modal shows up but it doesnot show the same modal the next time. Instead throws an error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'
```

Below is my code:

**Link to trigger ajax call:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#" class="open-edituser btn default btn-xs green-stripe">EDIT</a>
```

**Modal Pop Up**

```
<div id="edituser" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="modal-data"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo   Yii::t('user', 'Close'); ?></button>
</div>
</div>
```

**response from AJAX Call**

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-edituser", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#edituser').modal('show');
    $('#modal-data').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Any idea regarding this. Let me know.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this in your popup:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
    $cs->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
}
```

This will make sure jquery isn't reloaded when you open the popup. Without this line jquery will be loaded again and it will lose previous set functions and methods, like `.modal()`

Comment: I tried the solution but its still the same error msg. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: Hm, maybe you should also include the js files you're using for the modal in de scriptmap. Try adding those with `= false` to the scriptMap

Comment: You are totally right. Its working now. Thanks a lot. Cheers.